# Create a nested JSON object dynamically parent and child

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am trying to create a nested object like this:

```
[{
   "Countrys":{
                "CountryCode":"AF",
                "CountryName":"AFGHANISTAN",
                "CreatedBy":"admin@mail.com",
                "CreatedOn":null,
                "ModifiedBy":"Admin",
                "ModifiedOn":"/Date(1394094559000)/"
              },
    "StateCode":"BAM",
    "CountryCode":"AF",
    "StateName":"BAMIAN",
    "CreatedBy":"admin@mail.com",
    "CreatedOn":"/Date(1372617000000)/",
    "ModifiedBy":null,
    "ModifiedOn":null
    },
    ...........
]
```

**My code :**

```
    updateStateList = [];
    //state countrys data variable
    var stateCountrysCountryCode;
    var stateCountrysCountryName;
    var stateCountrysCreatedBy;
    var stateCountrysCreatedOn;
    var stateCountrysModifiedBy;
    var stateCountrysModifiedOn;

    //state open data variable
    var StateCode;
    var CountryCode;
    var StateName;
    var CreatedBy;
    var CreatedOn;
    var ModifiedBy;
    var ModifiedOn;

    $(".tableRow").each(function () {

        stateCountrysCountryCode = $(this).find("#erSLCountrysCountryCode").val();
        stateCountrysCountryName = $(this).find("#erSLCountrysCountryName").val();
        stateCountrysCreatedBy = $(this).find("#erSLCountrysCreatedBy").val();
        stateCountrysCreatedOn = $(this).find("#erSLCountrysCreatedOn").val();
        stateCountrysModifiedBy = $(this).find("#erSLCountrysModifiedBy").val();
        stateCountrysModifiedOn = $(this).find("#erSLCountrysModifiedOn").val();

        StateCode =  $(this).find("#erSLStateCode").val();
        CountryCode = $(this).find("#erSLCountryCode").val();
        StateName = $(this).find("#erSLStateName").val();
        CreatedBy = $(this).find("#erSLCreatedBy").val();
        CreatedOn = $(this).find("#erSLCreatedOn").val();
        ModifiedBy = $(this).find("#erSLModifiedBy").val();
        ModifiedOn = $(this).find("#erSLModifiedOn").val();

        CountrysObj = {};
        CountrysObj["CountryCode"] = stateCountrysCountryCode;
        CountrysObj["CountryName"] = stateCountrysCountryName;
        CountrysObj["CreatedBy"] = stateCountrysCreatedBy;
        CountrysObj["CreatedOn"] = stateCountrysCreatedOn;
        CountrysObj["ModifiedBy"] = stateCountrysModifiedBy;
        CountrysObj["ModifiedOn"] = stateCountrysModifiedOn;

        //state open data
        statesObj = {};
        statesObj["StateCode"] = StateCode;
        statesObj["CountryCode"] = CountryCode;
        statesObj["StateName"] = StateName;
        statesObj["CreatedBy"] = CreatedBy;
        statesObj["CreatedOn"] = CreatedOn;
        statesObj["ModifiedBy"] = ModifiedBy;
        statesObj["ModifiedOn"] = ModifiedOn;




        //CountrysObj.push(statesObj["StateCode"]);

        updateStateList.push({ "Countrys": CountrysObj });
        updateStateList.push(statesObj);

    });



    alert(JSON.stringify(updateStateList));
```

**I am getting like this Json:**

```
[{"Countrys":{"CountryCode":"AX","CountryName":"ALAND ISLANDS","CreatedBy":"admin@mail.com","CreatedOn":"","ModifiedBy":"Admin","ModifiedOn":"/Date(1394094559000)/"}},{"StateCode":"NS","CountryCode":"AX","StateName":"NOT SPECIFIED","CreatedBy":"admin@mail.com","CreatedOn":"/Date(1372617000000)/","ModifiedBy":"","ModifiedOn":""}]
```

In this result I get extra closing 2nd braces.

Comment: What is the question? You are not clear enough

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, doing:

```
x = {}
```

creates an object. That's why adding (pushing) it to an array creates the result of
    [{}]

What you want is to create an object of all state data, and have `countries` as a property of that object.

something like this:

```
//state open data
statesObj = {};
statesObj["StateCode"] = StateCode;
statesObj["CountryCode"] = CountryCode;
statesObj["StateName"] = StateName;
statesObj["CreatedBy"] = CreatedBy;
statesObj["CreatedOn"] = CreatedOn;
statesObj["ModifiedBy"] = ModifiedBy;
statesObj["ModifiedOn"] = ModifiedOn;
statesObj["Countries"] = CountrysObj;
```

Comment: Glad I could help @SoloThink. In StackOverflow it is customary to mark helpful posts by upvoting and/or marking helpful answers as the accepted answers.